# Avoid object instantiation in method

Tags: php, yii2

What is the best way to have one instance of some object in class? I'm using yii2-httpclient and use Client class. I have different methods thank make requests for differents web API but I think its bad idea to creating new object when calling method. I'm trying make instance in constructor but have error `"Call to a member function createRequest() on a non-object"`. How can I do this another way?

**My Controller:**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\httpclient\Client;

class ExchangeRates extends Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $client = new Client();
    }
    public function getPrivatRate()
    {
        // $client = new Client();
        $privatResponse = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5')
        ->send();
        return json_decode($privatResponse->content, true);
    }
    public function getNationalRate()
    {
        // $client = new Client();
        $nbuResponse = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=USD&date=20161101&json')
        ->send();
        return json_decode($nbuResponse->content, true);
    }
    public function getMejBankRate()
    {
        // $client = new Client();
        $mejResponse = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('http://api.cashex.com.ua/api/v1/exchange/mejbank')
        ->send();
        return json_decode($mejResponse->content, true);
    }
    public function getBlackMarketRate()
    {
        // $client = new Client();
        $blackMarketResponse = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('http://api.cashex.com.ua/api/v1/exchange/black-market')
        ->send();
        return json_decode($blackMarketResponse->content, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like this:

```
class ExchangeRates extends Model
{
    public $client;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->client = new Client();
    }
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$privatResponse = $this->client->createRequest()->...
```